# Does C have a facility which allows to fprintf to a string?

Tags: c

In Common Lisp, it does not really matter, what you parse from or write to - be it files or strings or other sequences. Functions like `make-string-input-stream`, `make-string-output-stream`, `with-input-from-string` etc. allow using the very same functions for reading and writing as you would on a text file (or socket, probably).

I always wondered, but never found anything definitive, as to whether it is possible to do the same in C, either with file descriptors (`int fd`) or with file streams (`FILE*`).

So, the question is, if there is something like that and if so, how does it look like?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo( FILE* out, const char* message) {
  fprintf(out, "%s\n", message);
}
int main( int argc, const char* argv[]) {
  char buffer[300];
  FILE* os = open_string_output_stream(buffer, 300);
  foo( os, "Hello World");
  close_string_output_stream(os);
  // buffer now contains "Hello World\n"
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Isn't it acceptable to directly format to a string via [`snprintf()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf)?

Comment: To clarify, you want a singular function to work with printing to either a file or to a buffer?

Comment: Yes it is about flexibility. If a function takes e.g. a `FILE* out`, the implementation should not care what is behind that.

Comment: You want the C++ stream operator.  But since the question is tagged `C`, it's not a valid answer.

Comment: I think in a project long long ago, someone told me they "attached FILE handles to some socket api in C"... ever since I had it in the back of my head, that there are options to do fun stuff.

Comment: You might be able to roll your own solution using C11's `_Generic` to select between expressions based on the type of your controlling expression (such as a `FILE *` versus a `char *`).

Comment: Did you consider using [SBCL](http://sbcl.org/)? If not, why?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I usually use SBCL - only for this (playing with intrinsics) I opted for C. But now I switched to c++, because... what was I thinking to consider C in the first place?! :)

Comment: Did you consider coding in SBCL (Common Lisp) a metaprogram which generates C code (in the spirit of http://swig.org/ ...),  or vice versa (on Linux) use several [pipe(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html) to communicate with some SBCL process....?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch The one weakness of a 64 bit Common Lisp is, that `uint64_t` is not possible because the values are tagged. So I could use FFI types or just switch to C++ to play with intrinsics. Later, I just might play with SBCLs VOPs and try to add the avx2 instructions to the Lisp compiler. Not sure yet. Right now, I just focus on learning what all those cryptic letter combinations (avx2 instructions) mean and do. As for compiling to C-code, there is a CL which does that (other than SBCL).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [snprintf(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/snprintf.3.html). You have to preallocate a buffer (of known size).

On Linux with [GNU libc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/), you also have [asprintf(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/asprintf.3.html). And you could even `fprintf` into a growing memory buffer (masquaraded as a `FILE*`) obtained with [open_memstream(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/open_memstream.3.html).

### This is Linux or GNU libc specific.

Notice that **GNU libc is [free software](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html)**, you can download and study -then improve- its source code.

On many operating systems, you could write to some temporary file (and register its removal with [atexit(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/atexit.3.html)). If portability is a major concern, use [tmpfile(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/tmpfile.3.html) and document that your software is using that (then the sysadmin could configure the OS, e.g. to have `/tmp/` in some [tmpfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmpfs) filesystem on Linux). Because of the [page cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_cache), a temporary file is likely to be in RAM.

Comment: `snprintf` is not what I am looking for. It is not the same code, writing to a string as it would be writing to a file.

Comment: So, install [Debian](http://debian.org/) on your laptop. Then you can use `open_memstream`

Comment: `open_memstream()` is basically what I am looking for. But its not part of Standard C runtime library... unfortunately.

Comment: Don't worry about `open_memstream` not being in the C standard. The standard for `libc` is POSIX. `libc` has a number of functions defined by POSIX that are _not_ in the C spec (e.g. `socket`, `connect`, `listen`, `accept`). Note that `*BSD` has `open_memstream`, so it's pretty safe to use it. As for WinX, well, who cares? :-) If you really want to have some fun, look at `fopencookie` et. al.

Comment: @BitTickler: you forgot a huge difference: **Linux is mostly open source** (or free software), and ***you* are allowed to improve its source code**. For Windows, it is not really true.